# why does my minimax for tic-tac-toe return undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I want to make an AI for tic-tac-toe with react hooks but I'm stuck cause my AI returns undefined here's the code I wrote

```js
const defaultScore = {
    0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0,
    3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0,
    6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0,
}
const winArray = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 6, 4]]
const compareWin = (a, b, c) => {
    return (c !== 0 && b === c && a === b)
}
const tryWin = (board: Object) => {//check if the game is in an end state
    let win = null
    winArray.forEach(v => {
        if (compareWin(board[v[0]], board[v[1]], board[v[2]])) {
            win = board[v[0]]
        } else if (!Object.values(board).includes(0)) {
            win = 'draw'
        }
    })
    return win
}
const AI = 'O'
const human = 'X'
```

function to copy and edit board without changing the real state

```js
const copyBoard = (original: Object, index?: any, newValue?: String) => {//
    const copiedBoard = { ...original }
    index = Number(index) // so it isn't a string
    if (index != null && newValue != null) {
        copiedBoard[index] = newValue
    }
    return copiedBoard
}
```

the minimax algorithm

```js
const miniMax = (board: Object, depth: number, isMax: Boolean) => {
    if (tryWin(board) != null) {
        const scoreOutcome = {
            [AI]: 10,
            [human]: -10,
            'draw': 0
        }
        return scoreOutcome[tryWin(board)]
    }


    const outcome = (isMax) ? -10000 : +10000

    if (isMax) {
        Object.keys(board).forEach(v => {

            if (board[v] === 0) {

                const simBoard = copyBoard(board, v, AI)
                const newOutcome = miniMax(simBoard, depth + 1, !isMax)

                return (typeof (newOutcome) == 'undefined') ? outcome : Math.max(outcome, newOutcome) //it was returning undefined sometimes so to ensure it will always return an integer to confirm that wasn't the problem 
            }
        })
    } else {
        Object.keys(board).forEach(v => {
            if (board[v] === 0) {

                const simBoard = copyBoard(board, v, human)
                const newOutcome = miniMax(simBoard, depth + 1, !isMax)

                return (typeof (newOutcome) == 'undefined') ? outcome : Math.min(outcome, newOutcome) //this does not return undefined

            }
        })
    }
}
const AImove = () => {
    let move
    let bestOutcome = -10000
    Object.keys(boardState).forEach(v => {
        if (boardState[v] === 0) {
            const simBoard = copyBoard(boardState, v, AI)
            const outcome = miniMax(simBoard, 0, true)
            console.log('outcome', outcome) //this returns undefined 
            if (outcome >= bestOutcome) {
                bestOutcome = outcome
                move = v
            }
        }
    })
    return move
}
const smartMoves = () => {
    const finalPlay = AImove()
    console.log('ai', finalPlay)

}
```

thank you in advance for the help I've been stomped for days about this
there's a sandbox for the full code https://8e3gr.csb.app/

Comment: Can you specify what function exactly is returning undefined?

Comment: Because only the `tryWin(board) != null` path actually returns something. The `return`s in the `.forEach()` callbacks are superfluous.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach(callbackFn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): _"`forEach()` executes the `callbackFn` function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` **it always returns the value `undefined`** and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain."_

Comment: The last item in winArray is it of order.

Comment: In the tryWin and miniMax functions consider using for..of loops if you want to return without completing all the looping iterations.

Comment: @AryeEidelman it's under the AImove that returns undefined, the last item of winarry is not in order but its not required it will still works fine, ill try the for of

Comment: @Andreas i don't quite understand could you explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

it is the for each function

```
Object.keys(boardState).forEach(v => {})
```

converting it to for...in or for...of

```
for(const i in boardState){}
for(const i of boardState){}
```

returns the expected results
the reason I'm not too sure and I don't want to spread inaccurate information so if you know please comment